# Apache2: inlcude php pages do not show!

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMP and PHPmyadmin; seems to work correctly; html and php files under `/var/www/html` show correctly. 
I set up my php.ini to look for include files here: `/srv/data/web/includes$`
so I modified the php.ini located here `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` as folowed:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/srv/data/web/includes"
```

But I got a blank page! I did the exactly the same on a fresh install on another computer and it is working. 
Any ideas where can be the problem?

Comment: The ; in front of the include_path variable. ;) Remove it.

Comment: @Frantique thanks, I did it but still not working

Comment: @Frantique I spoke to fast; needed to restart apache. Obviously! I was becoming crazy since yesterday! Thanksssssssssssss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process was the right one but stupidly enough I did not remove the comment mark in the php.ini

The correct code is (line 706)

```
;UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/srv/data/web/includes"
```

and restart apache services

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Voila 
Thanks @Frantique